# How to use a screen with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I tried to create an executable .sh file with command that create screen like this:

```
screen -dmS ast [comand]
```

And let my crontab execute it like this

```
* * * * * bash /root/my_bash.sh
```

But nothing executed, but with normal console command `bash /root/my_bash.sh` it's working successfully.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong about how you ran the script from the `crontab`.

[image: "Cron Job" by xmodulo is licensed under CC BY 2.0]

As per your issue description it looks the `crontab` try to use the `bash` command as the script.

For example:

To schedule the backup script to run every night at 2am, open the root user's `crontab`:

`$ sudo crontab -e`

then enter the following:

```
0 2 * * * /etc/scripts/backup.sh
```

For example, if you have a script that needs to create a file from the `dmesg` command once a day at 1pm, your entry looks like the following:

```
0 13 * * * /usr/bin/dmesg > ~/dmesg.txt
```

Try to removing the `bash` from the line in `crontab`

Comment: Part of my problem was solved, put the  `screen -dmS ast [command]` still not created

Comment: Are you on a system with selinux in enforcing mode, by any chance? Does getenforce exist and return something?